# Does Siege tool only accept 800 users at once?

Tags: load-testing, siege

When I read some article it said [Siege](https://www.joedog.org/siege-faq/) tool can accept 800 users concurrently. If so how can I simulate 1000 or 2000 users concurrently. Do I need more machines or can I run using multiple terminals?

when I run siege on multiple terminal  `-c500-d5`  500 hits for every 5 seconds, at a time I run on the 2 terminal,  but found that First terminal is running fine and other terminal gets fail,

Answer (score 1):

From the [Siege FAQ](https://www.joedog.org/siege-faq/#a16) there is nothing to conclude it has a maximum of concurrent users, it does offer some advice, but not on increasing the load.

> Keep in mind that -c256 -d1 translates to roughly 47,000 unique
>   visitors per day.

Each physical machine will have a certain limit based on CPU, Memory and number of network sockets. Technically a single machine could handle 10K+ connections, in [this question talks about 1,6 million simultaneous sockets connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651665/how-many-socket-connections-possible) on a pretty heavy machine.

Opening more terminals will probably not let you increase the number of connections on a single machines. You could just increase the `-c` number, until the machine gives an "Error: system resources exhausted" error or something similar. Experiment with what your machine can handle. Alternatively just try it and find out or [ask the same question to the developers at GitHub-issues](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege/issues).

If you need more load with Siege I think you should just get more physical or cloud-machines to run it on, just start some scripts at the same time. Have a look at [clustershh](https://github.com/duncs/clusterssh) to send the same command to multiple machines at the same time if timing is important for you.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://www.joedog.org/siege-manual/#a02 -d is a random delay between 1 and 10 in your case. So it each connection waits a random time before connecting again. This means 1500 users will connect between 1 and 10 seconds and then randomly keep repeating the connection each 1 - 10 seconds. So some seconds it will be more users than others, but never more than 1500.

Comment: So if I want to get the concurrent hit of 1000 users then I need to put the delay as 1 sec right ?

siege http://www.google.com -d1 -c5 -t1s
when I try this the output shows as 
Transactions:             2 hits
Availability:        100.00 %
Elapsed time:          0.58 secs
Data transferred:         0.02 MB
Response time:          0.44 secs
Transaction rate:         3.45 trans/sec
Throughput:          0.03 MB/sec
Concurrency:          1.50
Successful transactions:           4

Comment: -d1 and -c1000 could work yes, but I wonder what you are trying to achieve, because Siege seems not the tool for a controlled load-test. More a simple tool to hammer your server as a madman, but ask  detailed questions. Maybe jMeter is a better fit for you as it is a completer load-test tool. Also I think your extra questions are good new questions instead of comments.

Comment: It is a new question. Use the ask new question button.

Comment: @ Niels van Reijmersdal     https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/28268/analysing-the-siege-output   , This ismy question, please help me

Comment: Niels, the SO question you refer to speaks about 1600k requests/. Not 1.6k.

Comment: @PerLundberg You're totally right, edited the answer. Thanks.